# SQL running a count(*) and count(*) group by returns differnet number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is strange, lets say I have a table called dbo.internetquotes in `SQL server`.

I want to get the total number of quotes in a month and break it down by a column called quotetype.

I run the query:

```
select count(*) from dbo.internetquotes
where quotedate between '2014/03/01' and '2014/04/01';
```

and it returns 20k.

Now I run the query

```
select count(*), quotetype from dbo.internetquotes
where quotedate between '2014/03/01' and '2014/04/01'
group by quotetype;
```

And it returns the count per quotetype.  However, when i sum up the counts from the second query the number does not equal 20k (slightly less).  My thought was perhaps there are nulls in the column quotetypes but running a `select * where quotetype = null` returns 0 rows.

What is the reason for the discrepancies?

Comment: `quotetype = null` wont't work. You need `quotetype is null`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name still, the `GROUP BY` should return a row when `quotetype` is null

Comment: You should still get a count of null quotetypes they aren't filtered out of the count...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When anything does not match with aggregation, just think about three values - TRUE, FALSE, UNKNOWN.

You are probably dropping out the NULLS (UNKNOWN) when aggregating.

Also, please use > and < when dealing with dates.

[Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

```
-- 1 - Skip nulls
select 
    count(*) as Total
from 
    dbo.internetquotes
where 
    quotedate >= '20140301' and 
    quotedate < '20140401' and
    quotetype is not null

-- 2 - Skip nulls
select 
    quotetype, count(*) as total
from 
    dbo.internetquotes
where 
    quotedate >= '20140301' and 
    quotedate < '20140401' and
    quotetype is not null
group by 
    quotetype;
```

These two queries should have the same counts.  Good luck.

Just use Adventure Works and try these queries

```
-- 31465
select count(*) from [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader]

-- Group by person 
select SalesPersonID, count(*) as total
into #temp
from [Sales].[SalesOrderHeader] 
group  by SalesPersonID

-- 18 rows for a total count of 31465
select sum(total) as grand from #temp
```

The nulls will be group by and show up as a row.  I never discounted that.  But the date issue could drop data.  I champion that!

Comment: Using `>=` and `<` when dealing with dates vs `between` does not have any benefits, the query optimizer will turn `between` to a `>=` an `<` before execution, not to mention as long as both queries have the same `where` clause, they should produce similar results.  Also, if there are null `quotetype`'s, it will be included in the result as it's own `quotetype`, therefore that shouldn't be the problem

Comment: I totally disagree.  If the date has time that is at midnight, it does matter!  I bet you that my two queries have totals that equal each other.

Comment: @Tom the dates recommendation is so op uses the right range when dealing when `DATETIME`s. But I agree with the `NULL` quotetype, it should appear in op's result

Comment: @Lamak I would have the user try the > and <, since the totals work as expected in adventure works.  The only other idea is weird stuff with READ COMMITTED which can cause count issues.  Use RCSI or SNAPSHOT ISOLATION for the query and check the results.

Comment: @CRAFTYDBA Since the filter conditions are the same for both queries, I'm guessing that op isn't telling the whole story actually, or made an error when analizing the results

Comment: Yup, I would think so.  But may users mess up the date.  Use >= and < and be consistent.  Heading out for the day, have a good one!

Comment: o man - you guys are right.  I made a mistake analyzing the results.  you guys are right of course, aggregating should always match.  There were in fact no nulls but I copied the wrong cell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about it for a moment, I think you have duplicated rows or duplicated quotedate.

Can you run something like :

```
select count(distinct quotedate) from dbo.internetquotes
where quotedate between '2014/03/01' and '2014/04/01';
```

To compare with sum(counts) of 2nd query.